# Remove Blank Entry on DropDownList in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been looking but couldn't find any way to remove the blank item on my dropdown list.  Ideally, I would like to do this without altering the model.  I just want to remove the blank item from the dropdown list so that users are forced to select one (so they can't select "blank").

Note:  I am using the default dropdown list that comes with the MVC framework.

Here is my code:

```
' controller action:

ViewBag.CompanyId = New SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "Name")

' view:

@Html.DropDownList("CompanyId", String.Empty)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.CompanyId)
```

Comment: As Gaz Winter said in a comment below,`Remove the String.Empty that will get rid of it!`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you building the options for your dropdown?

I never have blank options.

I usually create my dropdown like this:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Client, new SelectList(Model.Clients))
```

Obviously your model options will be different.

**Answer:**  Remove String.Empty

Comment: The overload called with optionLabel will add the empty item --- @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Client, new SelectList(Model.Clients), "--- Select ---")

Comment: Yes i know how to add one. I am just asking how they are doing it to see where the problem lies :)

Comment: Remove the String.Empty that will get rid of it!

Answer (score 0):

Update on 2021: My problem was on the JS script side, I was appending an empty line within my dropdown :D

Like this:

```
$("#" + "YourID").append('<option></option>'); //Remove This Line

for (var i = 0; i < CountriesList.length; i++) 
{
$("#" + "YourID").append('<option  value="' + CountriesList[i] + '">' + CountriesList[i] + '</option>');
 }
```

Removing the first line will get you directly the first element from your Items list :)

Happy coding everyone.